# Application not installed error

Tags: android, eclipse

I have android 2.3.6 version of OS for my smart phone. I have Voice search google application installed. I have prepared simple application which converts voice to text.

1. AVD emulator does not support this service
2. When installing this application to phone, application not installed error received.

For option what is the probable case? What I think is the minimum api. In my Application I have manifest which includes

**android:minSdkVersion="10"** and
**android:targetSdkVersion="18"**

my mainActivity:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    protected static final int RESULT_SPEECH =1;
    private TextView txt1;
    private ImageButton bspeak1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        txt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        bspeak1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnSpeak);


    bspeak1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(
                    RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);

            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, "en-US");

            try {
                startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_SPEECH);
                txt1.setText("");
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException a) {
                Toast t = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Ops! Your device doesn't support Speech to Text",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                t.show();
            }
        }
    });

}

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }



protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode) {
    case RESULT_SPEECH: {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {

            ArrayList<String> text = data
                    .getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);

            txt1.setText(text.get(0));
        }
        break;
    }

    }
}
}
```

can anyone help me in this case?

Comment: Can you put your error log here?

Comment: in AVD, toast displays that service is not supported. On phone, during installation, application not installed message received. Don't have logcat for the phone runtime installation!

Comment: And what is the error in log when you try to install in your device ?

Comment: application not installed. Also when second time I tried to install, it says that the application you are trying to install will replace other application. All previous data will be saved.                                                                                                                                   WHOA! when previous application is not installed, how can this will replace it???    I remember that I have ssame package name for two different projects one is this and other. can same package name will create trouble?

Comment: Yes you have to change your pkg name.

Comment: Got it bro. Thanks. Will definitely try for it

Comment: Problem SOLVED. Thanks Trushit & Sagar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have android 2.3.6 version of OS for my smart phone.
>   For option what is the probable case? What I think is the minimum api. In my Application I have manifest which includes
>   android:minSdkVersion="10" and android:targetSdkVersion="18"

So there is nothing to do with the minimum api in menifest file.

One more thing you have to change your package name if some other app has the same package name Bcoz It creates ambiguity.